# what is the best and perfect solution to disable hover on mobile devices like iphone using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a big problem with the hover event on mobile phone like iphone, and you have tap two time to go to some link i find a code on internet to disable hover the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
      var el = $(this);
      var link = el.attr('href');
     window.location = link;
   });
});
```

that code is work fine but is come with another problem, the problem is any link with target="_blank" This has its flaws. If you click a link with target="_blank" it will open in the same window AND in a new window.

any one can give me a perfect solution to disable hover effect from iphone or any mobile device,

thank you

Comment: What is the purpose of that code as you understand it?

Comment: that code for you know to force click on a href target this code is solve perfectly the two tap problem but his open a link twice if the link have target _blank is opening newt tab and same windows

Comment: i recently came across this code and i find it awful. It has the terrible side-effect of overriding any progressive enhancments applied to `a` tags as any kind of code that delegates the clicks.

Comment: There's something else wrong - you should never have to resort to this for simply clicking on a link

Comment: can you give me a best solution another script for ex

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
      var el = $(this);
      var link = el.attr('href');
      if (el.attr('target') == '_blank') {
          window.open(link);
      } else {
          window.location = link;
      }
      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: is not work, first the link with blank is open in same window and second thing is i big problem, this code is open the link in just when i tap to scroll down